# Subtitle formats for youtube-dl

Tags: youtube, subtitles

Which format of the four srt|ass|vtt|lrc is 'cleanest' i.e. closest to a text with no meta- nor timing information, please?

Comment: Have you tried to check this yourself? It's just four files to look at.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "cleanest" but the most popular format is going to be SRT but VTT is popular for HTML5

Comment: SRT and VTT are probably the two likeliest competitors. But you're still going to need to parse them to get "just" the text out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to
- gronostaj (Polak? to dziekuje po polsku)
- Ryan and
- Anaksunaman

I have processed the VTT format with this and got a nice "clean" txt:

grep '<[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]>' 26.11subsMéxico.txt | sed 's/<[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]>//g' | sed 's$$$g' >clean.txt

Comment: All "<c>"  and "</c>" are gone from the command line above. But are necessary